# Error while testing flask application with unittest

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project'

while trying to run test_req.py
My project structure is:

```
├── instance/
│   ├── flask.cfg
├── project/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── base_processing.py
│   ├── models.py
|   ├── views.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── note.html
│   │   ├── notes.html
│   └── static/
│   │ 
│   └── tests/
│       ├── test_req.html
├── run.py
```

My UnitTest file is:

```
# project/test_req.py

    import unittest
    import os

    from project import app
    from project.models import db, User, Note
    from project.views import *

    TEST_DB = 'test.db'

    class RequestTests(unittest.TestCase):

        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            app.config['TESTING'] = True
            app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
            app.config['DEBUG'] = False
            app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + \
                os.path.join(app.config['BASEDIR'], TEST_DB)
            app.secret_key = 'staytrue'
            cls.app = app.test_client()

        def setUp(self):
            db.create_all()

        def tearDown(self):
            db.drop_all()


        def test_main_page(self):
            response = self.app.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

        def test_auth(self):
            u = User(username='testname1', password='1234567', email='cyber@mail.com')
            db.session.add(u)
            db.session.commit()
            response = self.app.post('/login', data=dict(username='testname1', password='1234567'), follow_redirects=True)
            with self.app.session_transaction() as sess:
                self.assertEqual(sess['username'], 'testname1')


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

Also my test work just fine with nose2, when I run it from my root directory. Also this is the first time I'm organizing my project layout this way.

Answer (score 1):

Module is not a folder, it should be a `.py` file. As you don't have `project.py` file, you should not specify `from project import app`.

Specifying `from project import app` means that there is `project.py` file and you want to import class `app` from this file.

if your `test_req.py` and `app.py` files are located in the same folder, then just use: `import app` in your `test_req.py`

Also replace:

```
from project.models import db, User, Note
from project.views import *
```

to

```
from models import db, User, Note
from views import *
```

Further reading:

- [Python
  modules](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm)
- [Importing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/import-module-python/)

Also, I would recommend to use [PyCharm Community Edition](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download), it is free, multilpatform and open source, and will help you to solve such tasks just via two mouse clicks.

---

Assume we have the following project structure in the root folder of our project:

```
/folder1/MyPythonFile1.py
/folder1/folder11/MyPythonFile2.py
/folder2/MyApp.py
```

[image: project structure]

`/folder1/MyPythonFile1.py` file looks like that:

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


class Class2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

And `/folder1/folder11/MyPythonFile2.py` file looks like that:

```
class Class3:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
```

File `/folder2/MyApp.py` uses classes from aforecited files and looks like that:

```
from folder1.MyPythonFile1 import Class1
from folder1.folder11.MyPythonFile2 import Class3

obj1 = Class1()
obj3 = Class3()
```

Apply this example to your particular case and update your imports accordingly.

Comment: Well, thank you for answer, but unfortunately my test not in the same directory. And I've already tried  `import app` and `from . import app` and also `from .. import app`.

Comment: thank you for help, unfortunately there's something generally wrong with my way of organizing code. I'll try to reorganize it.