# How to import python classes from another directory

Tags: python, kaggle

I am working in kaggle notebook.
I have uploaded a python script name `ResidualAttentionNetwork.py`. There is a class defined by name `ResidualAttentionNetwork`.
This class is uploaded into sub-folder.

Sub-folder is like :

```
input
  |_ residual_attention
      |_ Code
         |_ ResidualAttentionNetwork.py
```

My python code:

```
from Code.ResidualAttentionNetwork import ResidualAttentionNetwork
```

This throws an error : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Code'`

So I cant't get access to class `ResidualAttentionNetwork`.
Can you please help me.
[here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dOig8.png)

Comment: Show a pic of the directory. Make sure the directory has an __init__ file in it.

Comment: check this answer, probably it will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60069954/12576990

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read language basics about modules and [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) to understand how to add you `Code` folder into `sys.path`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have

```
__init__.py
```

file exists in the directory you want to import classes from .

Comment: `__init__.py` files are no longer necessary in Python 3.3+